# Getting Mac Address on Marshmallow In Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, android-6.0-marshmallow, mac-address

I've been trying several things to get the MAC on Android 6.0 with no success ):

I already have this permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

And this is my code:

```
public string GetMacAdress(Context context)
{
    string mac = GetMacAddressLegacy(context);

    if (mac == "02:00:00:00:00:00")
    {
        NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

        foreach (NetworkInterface nif in interfaces)
        {
            if (!nif.Name.ToLower().Contains("wlan")) continue;

            var physicalAddress = nif.GetPhysicalAddress();
            byte[] macBytes = physicalAddress.GetAddressBytes();
            if (macBytes == null) continue;

            string macString = BitConverter.ToString(macBytes);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(macString)) mac = macString.Trim().ToUpper().Replace("-", ":");
        }
    }

    return mac;
}

[Obsolete]
public string GetMacAddressLegacy(Context context)
{
    string toReturn =  "02:00:00:00:00:00";
    if (DetectWifiNetwork())
    {
        isConected = true;
        var telephonyMgr = (WifiManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
        toReturn = telephonyMgr.ConnectionInfo.MacAddress;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(toReturn)) toReturn = toReturn.Trim().ToUpper();
    }
    else
    {
        isConected = false;
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

But this line: `byte[] macBytes = physicalAddress.GetAddressBytes();` returns an empty array.

Anyone could solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this code:

```
public string GetMacAdress(Context context)
{
    string mac = GetMacAddressLegacy(context);

    if (mac == "02:00:00:00:00:00")
    {
        var interfaces = Java.Net.NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaces;

        foreach (var nif in interfaces)
        {
            if (!nif.Name.ToLower().Contains("wlan")) continue;

            byte[] macBytes = nif.GetHardwareAddress();

            string macString = BitConverter.ToString(macBytes);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(macString))   
                mac = macString.Trim().ToUpper().Replace("-", ":");
        }
    }

    return mac;
}
```

Comment: nif.GetHardwareAddress() returns nulls in macBytes in Android 11 is there any solution? or sample @Giorgi

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this method

```
public static string getMacAddress()
{
    string macAddress = string.Empty;

    var all = Collections.List(Java.Net.NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaces);

    foreach (var interfaces in all)
    {
        if (!(interfaces as Java.Net.NetworkInterface).Name.Contains("wlan0")) continue;

        var macBytes = (interfaces as 
        Java.Net.NetworkInterface).GetHardwareAddress();
        if (macBytes == null) continue;

        var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        foreach (var b in macBytes)
        {
            string convertedByte = string.Empty;
            convertedByte = (b & 0xFF).ToString("X2") + ":";

            if(convertedByte.Length == 1)
            {
                convertedByte.Insert(0, "0");
            }
            sb.Append(convertedByte);
        }

        macAddress = sb.ToString().Remove(sb.Length - 1);

        return macAddress;
    }
    return "02:00:00:00:00:00";
}
```

Comment: @jase Working! :) Thanks! Haha

Answer (score -1):

Well using this is enough to make it work:

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Code:

```
WifiManager wManager = (WifiManager)GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
WifiInfo wInfo = wManager.ConnectionInfo;
button.Text =  wInfo.MacAddress;
```

Are you testing on a real device or on a simulator?