# Unable to retrieve IP & MAC Address for wired network using Ethernet Manager for Android

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin.android, ethernet

I have developed an APP for an Android 4.4 device in which I am trying to retrieve the IP Address and MAC Address using **EthernetManager** for the wired network. Now when I am trying to run this application on the Android 5.1.1 device, I am not getting the IP Address and MAC Address. I have already provided the superuser access.

I’m having trouble getting this to work:

```
public string GetInterfaceName()=>(string)ethernetManager.Class.GetMethod("getEthernetIfaceName").Invoke(ethernetManager);
```

The error log:

> 2020-02-18 16:20:37.8485 [INFO] [4] HttpService - Attempting to get wired network connection data via 'GetWiredNetworkConfiguration' call.
>   2020-02-18 16:20:37.9114 [ERROR] [4] HttpService - getEthernetIfaceName []
>   2020-02-18 16:20:37.9114 [INFO] [4] HttpServer - Response to request /wired-network/configuration:
>   Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodException: getEthernetIfaceName []
>     at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0006e] in :0 
>     at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeAbstractObjectMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00014] in :0 
>     at Java.Lang.Class.GetMethod (System.String name, Java.Lang.Class[] parameterTypes) [0x00043] in :0 
>     at PatientPoint.Droid.NetworkConfiguration.Wired.EthernetManagerProxy.GetInterfaceName () [0x00015] in <3433561ce2794b26999a934f0ccf7c2a>:0 
>     at PatientPoint.Droid.NetworkConfiguration.Wired.WiredNetworkConnectionProvider.GetWiredNetworkConfiguration () [0x00000] in <3433561ce2794b26999a934f0ccf7c2a>:0 
>     at Deadpool.Droid.Core.HttpService.GetWiredNetworkConfiguration () [0x00015] in <33f384394b3e44efac7c863885fc43f1>:0 
>     --- End of managed Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodException stack trace ---
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getEthernetIfaceName []
>                   at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:664)
>                   at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:643)

The function to get the MAC Address:

```
private string GetMacAddress(string interfaceName)
{
    var ethernetInterface = NetworkInterface.GetByName(interfaceName);
    if (ethernetInterface != null)
    {
        var bytes = ethernetInterface.GetHardwareAddress();
        if (bytes != null)
        {
            var result = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                result.Append($"{bytes[i]:X2}");
                if (i != bytes.Length - 1)
                {
                    result.Append(":");
                }
            }
            return result.ToString();
        }
    }
    return "Not Available";
}
```

Please advise if the above method works for Android 4.4 or do I have to use some other method for Android 5.1.1 or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the mac address of android device, you could try the code below. I do not have Android 4.4 and 5.1.1, i test on Android 6.0 with no permission, it works well.

```
  public static string getMacAddress()
    {
        string macAddress = string.Empty;

        var all = Collections.List(Java.Net.NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaces);

        foreach (var interfaces in all)
        {
            if (!(interfaces as Java.Net.NetworkInterface).Name.Contains("wlan0")) continue;

            var macBytes = (interfaces as
            Java.Net.NetworkInterface).GetHardwareAddress();
            if (macBytes == null) continue;

            var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            foreach (var b in macBytes)
            {
                string convertedByte = string.Empty;
                convertedByte = (b & 0xFF).ToString("X2") + ":";

                if (convertedByte.Length == 1)
                {
                    convertedByte.Insert(0, "0");
                }
                sb.Append(convertedByte);
            }

            macAddress = sb.ToString().Remove(sb.Length - 1);

            return macAddress;
        }
        return "02:00:00:00:00:00";
    }
```

Get from the code:

[image]

Get from Android device:

[image]

I get the code from the similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43981078/11850033